# Partial hydrolysis of aluminium chloride

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

What is the meaning of partial hydrolysis of anhydrous aluminium chloride? What does the partial term signify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial means that it is not fully hydrolyzed.

A partially hydrolyzed solution of aluminium chloride will be slightly acidic.

The chemistry behind the hydrolysis of AlCl3 is quite interesting due to the fact that many different complexes can be formed.